# Logging variables defined in output/input

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm a little confused by this documentation. I may be reading this wrong, but the documentation says that you can add variables to the `input` object based on what you define in the text fields coming from what is given by the trigger. According to this picture, the user is defining 3 input variables `body`, `receiveDate`, and `subject`.
[image: https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/c30f2b170737ba3863c17b714662d9dd.png]
<sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/c30f2b170737ba3863c17b714662d9dd.png))</sub>

However in the code, they are referencing a variable called `plainBody` which hasn't been defined. How would this work?

Is there an object that I can log out that has every field that comes through in my trigger? Or do I have to define them as inputs using the input fields?

Edit: I also can't get any of the `z` libraries to work. According to this documentation: https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/built-functions-tools/#available-libraries I should be able to do something like

```
// let's call http://httpbin.org/get?hello=world with an extra header
var request = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://httpbin.org/get',
  params: {
    hello: 'world'
  },
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json'
  },
  auth: null,
  data: null
};

// perform asynchronously
z.request(request, function(err, response){
  console.log('Status: ' + response.status_code);
  console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  console.log('Content/Body: ' + response.content);
});
```

But I get an error that says `z is not defined theFunction`

Answer (score 1):

developer from Zapier here!

The data you provide in the `input` object is all that will be provided to your code when it runs; unfortunately it looks like there's a typo in that example screenshot (both of the checks in that conditional should be for `input.body`).

The documentation link you referenced is for the [Zapier Developer Platform](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/), which is how you add your own app to Zapier for other people to use. That also runs Javascript on the backend, so I see how it's easy for the two things to get mixed up!

You're looking for the documentation related to [running code in a Zap](https://zapier.com/help/code/).

To answer your question directly, there is no `z` object available in the *Code by Zapier* app. To make HTTP requests, you need to use the `fetch` library:

```
fetch('http://example.com/')
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
  }).then(function(body) {
    var output = {id: 1234, rawHTML: body};
    callback(null, output);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    callback(error);
  });
```

That code is taken from the [Introductory HTTP Example](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-http-example) in the linked documentation.

Hope that helps!